# The evasive gmodule-2.0 package

Tags: fedora, source

There are packages in Fedora production repos, which require `gmodule-2.0` package if compiled from source but I could not find any traces of this evasive package anywhere.

`dnf` is of no help as unlike `yum` it does not have a working `provides` command.

Does anyone know what should be installed to satisfy the requirement for this package? I found some mentions of this package in relation to `libglib2` but this package does not exist in the Fedora repos.

Comment: _Which_ packages exactly require the `gmodule-2.0` package? So we can reproduce this.

Answer (score 1):

Install `glib-devel` to satisfy the requirement. The message is misleading.